# Get input for unknown class fields during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, oop, reflection

I've been learning C# the past couple of months and we've been tasked with a small project where there's this specific requirement:

We need to design the UI part of the project in such way, that we can figure out some random class fields and then get the input from a user to initialize those fields.

For example, in one run of the program we have this class A that has two integer fields.
In the UI section, we need to figure out class A has two integers, then we need to receive 2 integers from the user and pass them back for initialization.

Another scenario:

We have class B that has a boolean and an Enum field, and we need to do the same.

I've been leaning towards using reflection to gather the data needed in runtime, but I'm having a lot of problem figuring out how to actually receive the required input from user.
Another hurdle is that we were told that reflection isn't gonna help us and/or not required to fulfill this task.

I'm fairly inexperienced with the language so I assume there may be some other ways to implement this that I'm not aware of, but conceptually speaking - I really can't grasp how it is possible.

Here's some basic classes hierarchy to give a better example:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    private Point location;
    private string color;
}

public abstract class NonCircular : Shape
{
    private int edgesNumber;
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    private float radius;
    private float diameter;
}

public class Triangle : NonCircular
{
    public enum AngleType { Right, Acute, Obtuse }
    public enum EdgePropery { Equilateral, Isosceles, Scalene }
    private AngleType angleType;
    private EdgePropery edgePropery;
    private float angle1, angle2, angle3;
}
```

Going with this example - let's say that class 'Triangle' is being added to the solution later-on, after the project is done.
We first construct the abstract class 'Shape' with some of the basic fields that are shared among everyone, and then according to the requirements, the UI needs to receive the fields:

> angleType, edgePropery, and angles1-3

and pass back values to the logical part of the project in order to initialize them properly.

Comment: Well it sounds like you really need reflection, but who gave you that requirement? The same person who said that reflection is not gonna help? Or did you misunderstand the requirement and this is the way that you've interpreted it? Why you need to "figure out some random class fields and then get the input from a user to initialize those fields"? What is the purpose of such a program?

Comment: The program is some sort of a "shape manager", i.e we have a basic shape, square, circle, triangle, etc. There are many instances of inheritance and as a result, polymorphism as well. The requirement to figure out the fields is to write the program in such way that, theoretically, someone could add another shape class into it (that shares the base class) and the program will run without any adjustments required in the UI section. The requirement is from the course's lecturer, and he's the one who said reflection isn't necessary to do it.

Comment: Why don't you show this code? So these classes without method bodies, just to illustrate the requirement.

Comment: Sure. I added some code to hopefully give a better example of my question.

Comment: You could add an abstract method to the base class that returns information on the fields that need to be initialized. Each shape then implements/overrides this method and returns its respective fields. A second method is needed to actually initialize the fields after the UI got to know the required fields.

Comment: How come `location` and `color` don't need to be initialized when initializing a `Triangle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to the base class that returns information on the fields that need to be initialized. Each shape then overrides this method and returns its respective fields.

A second method is needed to actually initialize the fields after the UI got to know the required fields and had the user enter the values.

The main problem then is that a subclass does not know about any private fields in its base class and can not initialize them. This can be solved by always calling the `base` implementation of `GetFieldInfo()` and `InitFields()` in every override.

To ensure the collection of provided values is "consumed" correctly you could use a stack. Every base class will `Pop()` as many values from the collection it needs to initialize itself and then leaves the rest to its derived classes.

The same principle is used when accumulating all the fields from base classes and derived classes with `GetFieldInfo()`.

Of course all this only works if the UI creates the `Stack` of values correctly, i.e. it must respect the order and `Type`s it got via `GetFieldInfo()`.

```cs
public abstract class Shape {
    private Point location;
    private string color;

    public virtual IEnumerable<Type> GetFieldInfo() {
        yield return location.GetType();
        yield return color.GetType();
    }

    public virtual void InitFields(Stack<object> values) {
        location = (Point)values.Pop();
        color = (string)values.Pop();
    }
}

public abstract class NonCircular : Shape {
    private int edgesNumber;
    
    public override IEnumerable<Type> GetFieldInfo() => base
        .GetFieldInfo()
        .Append(edgesNumber.GetType());
    
    public override void InitFields(Stack<object> values) {
        base.InitFields(values);
        edgesNumber = (int)values.Pop();
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape {
    private float radius;
    private float diameter;
    
    public override IEnumerable<Type> GetFieldInfo() => base
        .GetFieldInfo()
        .Append(radius.GetType())
        .Append(diameter.GetType());
        
    public override void InitFields(Stack<object> values) {
        base.InitFields(values);
        radius = (float)values.Pop();
        diameter = (float)values.Pop();
    }
}

public class Triangle : NonCircular {
    public enum AngleType { Right, Acute, Obtuse }
    public enum EdgePropery { Equilateral, Isosceles, Scalene }
    private AngleType angleType;
    private EdgePropery edgePropery;
    private float angle1, angle2, angle3;
    
    public override IEnumerable<Type> GetFieldInfo() => base
        .GetFieldInfo()
        .Append(angleType.GetType())
        .Append(edgePropery.GetType())
        .Append(angle1.GetType())
        .Append(angle2.GetType())
        .Append(angle3.GetType());
    
    public override void InitFields(Stack<object> values) {
        base.InitFields(values);
        angleType = (AngleType)values.Pop();
        edgePropery = (EdgePropery)values.Pop();
        angle1 = (float)values.Pop();
        angle2 = (float)values.Pop();
        angle3 = (float)values.Pop();
    }
}
```

---

It just occured to me that using `GetType()` might count as reflection. But `GetFieldInfo()` could also return an `IEnumerable<object>` created from the field values directly. The UI could then use the [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) to check the field type and show the appropriate UI element (text box, number box, drop down etc).

---

By the way, I think this is a rather ugly solution. The back-and-forth between the base and sub classes makes for highly unreadable code. In a real-world application I'd probably rather take the performance hit of using reflection in favor of having the type inspection and initialization logic in one place. In the above solution this logic is spread all over your model classes.